An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error
An exception error occurred on my pipelline build in AzureDevOps in the event that I'm connecting to a SVN repository server. Below is the actual error message. Hopefully you can give me an advice or possible solution for this.
Process Name: TfsJobAgent
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Detailed Message: An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: URL
Have tried bypassing the security endpoint hoping that's the solution but still the same.

Also, has it worked previously or is this a new repository? Where is the repository located and are you using a MS-hosted build agent or a self-hosted agent?

@bryanbcook, No previous because it is the first and current setup. The repository is internal and the agent is also internal as it is self-hosted agent. The solution posted on the similar question above is the repo becoming public but this is not possible for us. The repo should be private because this is being used for internal purpose only not for internet.

Hi there, Welcome to SO. Can you please double check if your SVN repo URL is resolvable on that agent machine? Have your tried git clone to test the connection? What if you use the IP of the SVN server instead of its domain?

If the agent machine was from the same network/subnet of the SVN server, it should be able to visit the server via private IP, if you don't expect the server to go public.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT, Hello Alvin, The URL is resolvable and no problem with the domain. For the git clone, can I ask how to perform this? I'm new to this command. Thank you.

May I know if your pipeline was using a Microsoft-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent? If running a self-hosted agent, how did you test the connection between your agent machine and the SVN server?
